# How to properly detect end-of-file condition in an SDL2 RWops?

Tags: c, io, sdl

SDL2 defines an stream-like IO abstraction, `SDL_RWops`, which supports read, write, seek, etc.

The documentation for the `SDL_RWops` [read function](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWread) says that each implementation

> Returns the number of objects read, or 0 at error or end of file; call
>   SDL_GetError() for more information.

Since the same error code is used for both error and EOF, there is not a way to distinguish between these two conditions with just this call.  There does not appear to be any other way to query a `RWops` for the end-of-file condition.

The signature for `SDL_GetError()` is:

```
const char* SDL_GetError(void)
```

...in other words it too is wholly unsuitable for distinguishing between these conditions.

So how can we know if there was an error, or the stream has simply reached the end-of-file?

One nice thought would be to use a `SDL_RWseek()` to get the current position of the stream, then seek to the end, compare the two positions, and seek back.  However, this doesn't work in general - because not all streams can seek (for example a network stream implementation, or a stream which is on-the-fly decompressing from the input of some other stream, etc...  in general seek may just not be supported).

Comment: In SDL3, this is fixed - there is a field named `status` in the `RWops` structure that was added.   It can be queried directly for this information.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is call SDL_ClearError() before you start using SDL_RWread(). When SDL_RWread() returns 0, you check with SDL_GetError() if there was an error. If there was an error, SDL_GetError() will return a string describing the error. If SDL_GetError() returns an empty string, it means there was no error, hence SDL_RWread() returned 0 for EOF.